# VLOOKUP nested inside a LOOKUP, showing improper vaule when LOOKUP takes over

Tags: excel-formula

```
=LOOKUP(VLOOKUP(L2,Ticket_Import!B:D,2,FALSE),Admins_Techs!A:C,Admins_Techs!B:B&" "&Admins_Techs!C:C)
```

The breakdown is this, VLOOKUP gives the proper result, but when LOOKUP takes over, it shows the last entry in the excel sheet.

I would think that I could put in "FALSE" at the end of LOOKUP, but the problem I am seeing is that the part that is normally reserved for that is the answer that is required for the lookup.  which is the tech's first and last name.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Lookup does not have an Exact Match, the data must be sorted.  Use two VLookups instead:

```
=VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(L2,Ticket_Import!B:D,2,FALSE),Admins_Techs!A:C,2,FALSE)&" "&VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(L2,Ticket_Import!B:D,2,FALSE),Admins_Techs!A:C,3,FALSE)
```

---

If one has the Dynamic Array formula XLOOKUP:

```
=XLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(L2,Ticket_Import!B:D,2,FALSE),Admins_Techs!A:A,Admins_Techs!B:B&" "&Admins_Techs!C:C,"",0)
```

Comment: There is no other way? I'm not saying it doesn't work, but it just seems clunky... I'm just asking because it doesn't feel elegent... if that makes sense? 

I appreciate the help, don't get me wrong, I am just looking for formulas as clean as I can get them. 

Thanks again.

Comment: If you have XLOOKUP, then yes.  Otherwise, no.